# How to disable diff-hl when browsing remote files?

Tags: package, tramp

When using Tramp and while browsing remote files `diff-hl` hangs Emacs. How is it possible to disable this package only when accessing remote files?

Comment: I suggest you `M-x report-emacs-bug` about the fact that diff-hl makes Emacs hang when used in remote files.

Comment: @Stefan I've got the impression that [diff-hl.el](https://github.com/dgutov/diff-hl/) does not belong to vanilla-emacs. Shouldn't the bug report go to [the diff-hl issues](https://github.com/dgutov/diff-hl/issues/new) instead? Maybe [Dmitry](https://github.com/dgutov) will determine whether the bug is related to vanilla-emacs or not. (Just IMHO.)

Comment: @Tobias: I think either way will work, yes.

Comment: Done: https://github.com/dgutov/diff-hl/issues/100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`global-diff-hl-mode`](https://github.com/dgutov/diff-hl/blob/bec9889de7bf48d28826039880cec9bfad24a628/diff-hl.el#L592-L594) uses `turn-on-diff-hl-mode` and [the comment in `diff-hl.el`](https://github.com/dgutov/diff-hl/blob/bec9889de7bf48d28826039880cec9bfad24a628/diff-hl.el#L47-L50) says that one should use `turn-on-diff-hl-mode` for buffer local activation of `diff-hl`.

So it seems reasonable to advice `turn-on-diff-hl-mode`:

```el
(require 'diff-hl)
(require 'tramp)

(defun turn-on-diff-hl-mode-ad ()
  "Turn on `diff-hl-mode' avoiding remote tramp files
or `diff-hl-dir-mode' in a buffer if appropriate."
  (cond
   ((and buffer-file-name
     (null (tramp-handle-file-remote-p (buffer-file-name))))
    (diff-hl-mode 1))
   ((and (eq major-mode 'vc-dir-mode)
     (null (tramp-handle-file-remote-p default-directory)))
    (diff-hl-dir-mode 1))))

(advice-add 'turn-on-diff-hl-mode :override #'turn-on-diff-hl-mode-ad)
```

Disclaimer: I do not have `diff-hl` installed on my system.
Please test this proposal and report in the comments whether it works or not.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But for some reason if I opened a local file and that started diff-hl package and then started a remote file then browsed in the directories with dired, emacs still hangs and when trying to exit I see the diff-hl active process still active.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for the edit. Aren't quote and sharp quote equivalent in emacs? I believe [it makes a difference in Common Lisp](https://colinxy.github.io/computer-science/2016/05/10/a-first-step-in-lisp.html), but I don't know that. In emacs I generally use sharp quotes for function symbols. But maybe that is a bad habit?

Comment: @Tobias: yes, both forms work, so the difference is in the intention, and the general rule there is to use `#'` in those places where a `(lambda ...)` could appear (e.g. the third arg of advice-add but not the first).

Comment: @Stefan I'll try to keep that in mind. Thanks.